# Kohana not displaying error handler

Tags: kohana-3

Kohana does not displaying its built-in error handler (such as this: http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/errors#example).

When there is an error somewhere in my script it just says:

> "ErrorException [ 8 ]: Array to string conversion ~ SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Log/Writer.php [ 81 ]"

I wrote

```
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

Kohana::init(array(
    ...
    'errors' => true));
```

but it doesn't work.

How to enable error handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Kohana error handler is enabled and it does work.

You're seeing a short error message instead of a full stack trace because there's something wrong happening in your Log Writer.

When a built-in error page is generated it's wrapped in a `try/catch` block. If anything wrong happens during the process (there's several things that might fail, e.g. Log Writer in your case) the exception thrown is caught and is returned in plain text, as in your question. You can see how this works in [Kohana Docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Kohana_Exception#response).

I'd look why Log Writer tries to convert array to string.

Comment: Thank you for idea.
There is a bug in Kohana: http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/11567/kohana-3-3-strtr-array-to-string-conversion-issue-in-kohana_log_writer/p1